# Negative numbers returned in a factorial Function (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, factorial, negative-number

I have the following code to calculate n!

```
import numpy as np

print "n! (for n<31)"
print

n = input("Enter n: ")

lst = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    lst.append(i)

print lst     #Just to see if the program is working

print "n!: ", np.prod(lst)
```

However, for some numbers, the program returns a negative value.

Eg. 
The following is from the console when I ran it for n = 20:

```
n! (for n<31)

Enter n: 20
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
n!:  -2102132736
```

It also happens for n = 32
However, the program does work for other numbers, eg. 3! returns 6, as it should.

Can someone please explain.

Comment: Which python and bumpy version are you using? I don't see any negative numbers when running with python 2.7.5… It could be a 32bit problem. Ahm, I just noticed that 20 is the highest number which does not return a negative number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, it's a 32bit problem. If you have a 64bit system, you can still calculate up to 20!

Here is a solution without numpy, with the python builtin types, which handle such problems pretty safely:

```
def factorial(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        result *= i
    return result

n = input("n! (for n<31)\n\nEnter n: ")
print("n!: %d" % factorial(n))
```

And here is a recursive function to bend your mind ;-)

```
def factorial_r(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return n * factorial_r(n-1)

n = input("n! (for n<31)\n\nEnter n: ")
print("n!: %d" % factorial_r(n))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a link to the documentation for numpy's prod function:

[numpy.prod](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html#numpy.prod)

If you go to the bottom of that page, you'll see the very last example says that when x (the given parameter to the function) is an unsigned integer, the result that gets returned is a *default platform integer*. So numpy will not convert the result into a long type when the result exceeds that which can be stored in a 32 bit integer, like python usually does. So you are getting integer overflow.

if you declare a function:

```
def fact(n): return 1 if n == 1 else (n * fact(n-1))
```

and do:

```
fact(20)
```

you get:

```
2432902008176640000L
```

which is the correct value for 20!.

By the way, doing:

```
lst = []
for i in range(1,n+1):
    lst.append(i)
```

is not ideal. Python's range function can do this easily! try:

```
lst = range(1, n + 1)
```

You're already doing this in your for-loop! You can test it in the interpreter:

```
>>> range(1, 20 + 1)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that the range function creates a list. Thanks!

Comment: `np.prod(np.arange(1,21,dtype=np.uint64))` works just fine. You can also use floats for larger factorials, though they are not exact.

Comment: @Ophion So you can tell it to use a 64 bit int? Numpy is pretty awesome!

Comment: Yes, numpy will only change the `dtype` if the `dtype` is of `int` **and** the precision is less then the default platform integer precision.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect Numpy is creating an array of 32-bit ints.

Therefore you are seeing integer overflow when n! is greater than the limit of a 32 bit integer.

try:

```
 print "n!: ", np.prod(lst, dtype=np.uint64)
```